# How to properly align Tikz pictures in Latex fraction environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, fractions, alignment

How to properly align Tikz pictures in Latex environment to get the following picture?

[image]

My trial code does not compile,

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    A = \frac{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) to[bend left] (1,0) to[bend left] (0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \def\L{1.0} 
            \matrix[column sep=.1cm, row sep=2mm]
            {   
                \draw (0,0) to[bend left] (\L,0) to[bend left] (0,0);
                &
                \node at (0,0) {$-$};
                &
                \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (\L,0);
                \draw[xshift=\L cm] (0,0) to[bend left] (\L,0) to[bend left] (0,0); \\
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please, extend your code fragment to complete small document ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you can control the vertical alignment with the `baseline` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    A = \frac{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,-0.1)}]
            \draw (0,0) to[bend left] (1,0) to[bend left] (0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,-0.1)}]
            \draw (0,0) to[bend left] (1,0) to[bend left] (0,0);
     \end{tikzpicture}
     -
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,-0.1)}]
            \draw (0,0) to[bend left] (1,0) to[bend left] (0,0);
            \draw[dashed](0,0) -- (-1,0);
     \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know what these objects represent, so you may want to use another baseline.

Note that you can use a Ti*k*Z matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    A = \frac{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \draw (0,0) to[bend left] (1,0) to[bend left] (0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \def\L{1.0} 
            \matrix[column sep=.1cm, row sep=2mm,ampersand replacement=\&]
            {   
                \draw (0,0) to[bend left] (\L,0) to[bend left] (0,0);
                \&
                \node at (0,0) {$-$};
                \&
                \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (\L,0);
                \draw[xshift=\L cm] (0,0) to[bend left] (\L,0) to[bend left] (0,0); \\
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the more versatile `matrix` in `tikzpicture` does not work with `\frac`. Although `baseline` is one answer to this figure, it will become difficult to deal with multiple rows of figure in the denominator.

Comment: @KevinPowell You can definitely use a matrix, just add `ampersand replacement=\&` and replace `&` by `\&`.

Comment: That's quite neat!  Why `[baseline]` option centers the figure in the numerator? It is black magic for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\[
A = \frac{\tikz[baseline=1pt]{\draw  (-1.5,0) to[bend left] (-0.5,0) to[bend left] (-1.5,0);}}
         {\tikz{\draw  (-1.5,0) to[bend left] (-0.5,0) to[bend left] (-1.5,0)
                       ( 0.5,0) to[bend left] ( 1.5,0) to[bend left] ( 0.5,0);
                \draw[dashed, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm] (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0);}
         }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How is that different from my answer except that you define `\M` but do not use it? The only thing apart from the unused definition I can see is the use of `baseline`, which is precisely what I am using.

Comment: @marmot the denominator is different. I think there's an error here, because the minus is missing.

Comment: I would create a `pic` for the shapes, and suggest to use dots instead of dashes, which could be confused with the minus (@marmot, too).

Comment: @CarLaTeX That's a brilliant idea!

Comment: @marmot, definition of `\M` is left from some my experiments (now deleted). baseline is used slightly differently. also coordinates of elements are different. however you still can look on my answer as small variation of yours ... (but i wrote it without seeing yours).